# How to know which is the previous Activity in Android?

Tags: android

Suppose there are 3 activities like X,Y and Z.
X and Y have two different buttons and in both button click I start the Z activity. There is a requirement that how to check from which Activity Z get started ?

Any help please?
Thanks

Comment: i think you should use bundle and send on startactivity and in bundle send string and check from which ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the launching activity's name in the intent itself.

intent.putExtra("class","com.sample.ActivityX");

Answer (score 2):

You can send data from X or Y to Z. For that, when launching the new activity you create an intent. So you just have to do:

intent.putExtra("key", "value");

In activity Z, to get the extra value you do:

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String value = extras.getString("key");